# Saving files in Python using "with" method

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am wanting to create a file and save it to json format. Every example I find specifies the 'open' method. I am using Python 2.7 on Windows. Please help me understand why the 'open' is necessary for a file I am saving for the first time.

I have read every tutorial I could find and researched this issue but with no luck still. I do not want to create the file outside of my program and then have my program overwrite it.

Here is my code:

```
def savefile():
    filename =  filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = 
    "./Documents/WorkingDirectory/",title = "Save file",filetypes = (("JSON 
    files","*.json"), ("All files", "*.")))
    with open(filename, 'r+') as currentfile:
        data = currentfile.read()
    print (data)
```

Here is this error I get:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\CurrentUser\Desktop\newproject.py", line 174, in savefile
>       with open(filename, 'r+') as currentfile: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   u'C:/Users/CurrentUser/Documents/WorkingDirectory/test.json'

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out! The problem was the mode "r+". Since I am creating the file, there is no need for read and write, just write. So I changed the mode to 'w' and that fixed it. I also added the '.json' so it would be automatically added after the filename.

```
def savefile():
    filename =  filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = 
    "./Documents/WorkingDirectory/",title = "Save file",filetypes = (("JSON 
    files","*.json"), ("All files", "*.")))
    with open(filename + ".json", 'w') as currentfile:
        line1 = currentfile.write(stringone)
        line2 = currentfile.write(stringtwo)
        print (line1,line2)
```